# How do I change Lego Batman 2's language to English?

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

I acquired Lego Batman 2 through Steam, and my Windows 7 is in Brazilian Portuguese. The game starts with Portuguese subtitles and there doesn't seem to be a way to change it to English.

Usually there is a menu to change the game language, but I don't see it anywhere on this title.

Comment: I thought lego characters couldn't talk. Man I miss the original Lego Star wars.

Comment: @hammythepig: No not for this one, there's actual dialogue in this game.

Comment: they still talk in English... but the subtitles and menus are all in Portuguese, and I can't even turn off the subtitles

Answer (score 2):

Change language to English

1- Go to regedit

2- Find this location: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Wow6432Node \ Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment \ LEGOBatman2". If it does not exist, create it. (Note that if the Key "Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment" already exist, make sure it includes "Bros." instead of "Bros". If not, change it so it contains the period).

3- Find or create the value LanguageVal with the hexadecimal value representing the language your game currently is on. You simply have to change it for the English number, which is 409.